# How Can I send An Email using genexus evo 3 for web

Tags: c#, smtp, genexus

Can somebody help me to resolve this problem.

I was trying  to use some Data type such as SMTSession, MailMessage, MailRecipient.

But it does not work.

Here is the code.

```
    &SMTPSession.Host                  = 'smtp.gmail.com'<br>
    &SMTPSession.Port               = 465<br>
    &SMTPSession.Authentication     = 1<br>
    &SMTPSession.UserName           = 'XXXX@gmail.com'<br>
    &SMTPSession.Password           = 'password'<br>
    &SMTPSession.Secure             = 1 <br>
    &SMTPSession.Sender.Address     = 'XXXX@gmail.com'<br>
    &SMTPSession.Sender.Name        = 'OtherName'<br>
    &MailRecipient.Address          = 'XXXX@hotmail.com'<br>
    &MailRecipient.Name             = 'Name'<br>
    &MailMessage.Subject            = 'Subject'<br>
    &MailMessage.Text               = 'text'<br>
    &MailMessage.To.Add(&MailRecipient)<br>


    &SMTPSession.Login()
    if &SMTPSession.ErrCode <> 0
        &SMTPSession.Send(&MailMessage)  
        &SMTPSession.Logout()
   endif
```

Genexus Evolution 3 Upgrade 2, .Net Environment, Web

Answer (score 0):

Try with 587 port.

Could you add the Error Description?

Have you [enabled 32 bit application](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx) in App Pool IIS?

Comment: 587 is STARTTLS, starts as plain text and then switches to TLS, so it should have secure=0 (doesn't force TLS before starting).

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine.
The only difference with what I've done is that I wrote &error = &SMTPSession.Login ()

The Gmail account you are using does not have two steps verification enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fully ok, you just missed the status checking before sending,

```
&SMTPSession.Login()
if &SMTPSession.ErrCode = 0 // 0 = OK
    &SMTPSession.Send(&MailMessage)  
    &SMTPSession.Logout()
else
   //Msg(&SMTPSession.ErrDescription) // to see what kind of error
endif
```

For my case I used Gmail SMTP and the port was 587

Answer (score 0):

In order to send mail from GX program, you must activate in the sender Google account the option to allow less secure apps.